# What is the secondary part of a book/play title called?

Tags: single-word-requests

It''s quite common for academic papers and such to have a short title intended to catch the casual browsers's interest, followed by *colon* and a longer more explanatory alternative.

I know [this](http://www.questia.com/library/book/the-expansion-of-new-england-the-spread-of-new-england-settlement-and-institutions-to-the-mississippi-river-1620-1865-by-lois-kimball-matthews-rosenberry.jsp) is a lousy example (I couldn't easily find a better/shorter one), but even so I'm sure this *Catchy Title : Longer version conveying more information about the work* format is also used in fictional works.

Is there a standard name for that secondary title. It's not really an "alternative title". The only thing that comes to mind for me is [byline](http://desktoppub.about.com/od/glossary/g/byline.htm), but I know that's not right either.

Comment: You may have been thinking of [strapline](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strapline) when you wrote "byline."

Comment: @Rhodri: Yes! Thanks for that! I *knew* there was something akin to *byline* that I couldn't recall. Though I had a sneaking suspicion even if I *could*, it wasn't going to have exactly the meaning I wanted. I feel another question coming on now though...

Comment: Note: titling has taken a turn for the bizarre. Exhibit A: the [Die Hard film series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Hard_(film_series)). #2 film was called simply Die Hard 2, and featured a by-line of "Die Harder" on the movie posters and most other promotions. Die Hard 3 was officially titled "Die Hard with a Vengeance", frequently with a colon in it, making "with a Vengeance" a by-line, but it had other by-lines as well. #'s 4 and 5 reversed their formula, ending with "Die Hard" instead. All that is just to say that the line distinguishing title, subtitle and by-line is not at all clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Subtitle**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subtitle):

> a secondary or subordinate title of a literary work, usually of explanatory character.

I know we usually think of that word in the "I prefer to *read* my foreign movies" context, but this is definition #1 and, I suspect, the original meaning.

Comment: Brilliant. I'm *very* used to **subtitles** in the movie context, on account of always needing to find them for my nonagenarian father who's getting a bit deaf but still loves watching old westerns. But - yes, this probably *was* the original meaning, given chronology and the advance of technology.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably said it was the ["long title"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_title). The "Catchy Title" is called the [short title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_title), and provides an easy name to call it by, then the "long title" provides a more comprehensive description of the article.

Comment: Nah. It's definitely the *subtitle*. Even though that word is now familiar with a totally different meaning to half the non-English-speaking world as they watch their pirated Hollywood blockbusters.

Comment: I know it is a *subtitle* or a sort of *subtitle*, I am just providing the specific name for it, as I have learned.

Comment: Intriguing.  The specific names I learned are _title_ and _subtitle_.  _Long title_ and _short title_ are just noun phrases to me, without anything like the specificity you are giving them.